# TDBGrid - индикатор не перемещается с перемещением выделенной строки

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Уважаемые программисты, прошу подсказать: в чем может таиться причина того, что с перемещением выделения при помощи ролика мыши индикатор TDBGrid не перемещается? И какие есть решения для избежания этой проблемы?

Comment: присоединяюсь к вопросу, мне тоже интересно

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "индикатором"? Скроллбар?

Comment: @teanЫЧ в Options TDBGrig можно подключить dgIndicator указав в соответствующем поле значение true, после этого в таблице появляется столбец, в котором определенным символов показывают активную строку TDBGrig. При прокручивании роликом мыши выделение перемещается по строкам, а значение индикатора остается на том же месте.

Comment: 1-я ссылка в гугле http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2002/a/bltip1102_3.htm

Comment: Большое спасибо - очень помогло!:)